# Matlab Code is running into an Invalid expression error

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I keep running into this error:
File: secant.m Line: 8 Column: 21
Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use
parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters.

```
clear; clc; close all; format long;

function [approx] = secant(f ,x0, x1)

iter = 1000;    %max iterations
tol = 10^(-6);  %how close do I need to get?

for i = 1:iter
    approx = (x0*f(x1)-x1*f(x0))/(f(x1)-f(x0));
    x0 = x1;
    x1 = approx;
    error = abs(x1-x0);
    if (error<tol)
        break
    end
end

if (i==iter)
    fprintf('Exceeded max iterations, no convergence!')
else
    fprintf('Within tolerance after %g iterations. \n',i)
    fprintf('Approximation to the root: %g',approx)
end
end
```

I've looked at solution to it on other sites but none of their solutions have been working, I made sure I had brackets & parenthesis in the appropriate places. And doubled checked that how I wrote my for loop was valid with the MatLab documentation. Not exactly sure where else to check at this point.

I'm currently running it through the command window with f as:

- f = @(x) x*euler(1)^x-cos(x)-1

and calling it as:

- secant(f,0.5,1)

I should be getting something close to 0.7820389... after ~6 iterations.

Comment: Which is line 8? Please copy-paste the full error message.

Comment: Do you really have `clear` at the top of your file, before the function declaration? If so, the file is a script, and your function won’t be called.

Comment: Code runs fine for me (I removed the `clear` line) and returns something close to `pi` actually. Are you possibly using Octave instead of Matlab or do you not have the Matlab Symbolic Math Toolbox? The function `euler` is a symbolic math function (and `euler(1)` just equates to zero anyways).